# Как найти повторяющиеся символы?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Как в массиве символов можно определить 2 повторяющихся символа?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int n = 100;
    char word[n];
    int answ = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cin >> word[i];
        if (word == "AA") answ += 1;
    }
    cout << answ;
    return 0;

    
}
```

Хочу написать условие что "Если в массиве встречаются "AA", то answ +=1", но программу крашает, как можно было бы это реализовать?

Comment: `strstr(word,"AA") != NULL)`

Comment: В какой диапазон индексов `i` пишет оператор `cin >> word[i];` ?